# FFmpeg: Invalid NAL unit size after Concat filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 3 videos using Concat filter.
The videos are:

Video1

> Duration: 00:00:05.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45584 kb/s
>   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 45653 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

Video2

> Duration: 01:12:18.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 730 kb/s
>   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 704x352 [SAR 457:704 DAR 457:352], 599 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)

Video3

> Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25827 kb/s
>   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25812 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

The ffmpeg command that I use is:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setdar=16/9[v0];
[1:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setdar=16/9[v1]; 
[2:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setdar=16/9[v2];
[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" 
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
(I have tried also with force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease)
```

However I get the following error

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55b7422ea700] stream 1, offset 0xbac62: partial files dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.989x
[h264 @ 0x55b742be9a20] Invalid NAL unit size (110724 > 17746).
[h264 @ 0x55b742be9a20] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
video3.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
video3.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 2 times
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Invalid data found when processing input
video3.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
Last message repeated 1 times
```

and the output.mp4 is only video1+video2.

BUT! If I use a sample of video2.mp4 (for example the first 10 minutes of it), the ffmpeg command runs successfully till the end, generating the expected output (video1+video2+video3).

Do you know why do I get this error and how could I cope with it?

**UPDATE**:
My command works perfectly with a downgraded version of FFmpeg. Maybe there is a bug in the newest one?

Comment: Share the three files.

Comment: Finally, my command works perfectly with a downgraded version of FFmpeg. Maybe there is a bug in the newest one?

Comment: We can check for a regression if you provide some files so we can duplicate this issue.

Comment: @green_hat can you share me downgraded version of FFmpeg ?

Comment: @Imran I don't work on this project anymore. But as I remember it was one version from 2.1.8 "Fourier" till 2.6.9 "Grothendieck".